# Why is this question about the usefulness of nulls "primarily opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

**[When is null useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647978/when-null-is-useful)** has been closed as primarily opinion-based, and I can't understand why. Look at the first answer:

> For example, if you have a model where you aim to produce little or no garbage, Optional is not an option and `null` produces no garbage.

This is a perfectly factual and helpful answer, and doesn't seem opinion-based at all. I don't really understand why this is not a valid question. Can I get an explanation so I can improve my questions in future?

Comment: Is that the only thing null could be used for? There are a lot more possibilities that that. For example you might null out data that is no longer correct and then lazy load it on next use. There are also a lot of stylistic usages

Comment: @RichardTingle that would more make it too broad?

Comment: @rene I'm sitting on the fence between those two anyway; i probably would have voted too broad. However the use of null can often be stylistic which is opinion based

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah, yeah. And all best-practices are primarily opinion based.

Comment: `But are there any other use-cases when it's useful or when it's the best option?` <-- Primarily opinion-based. That being too broad is also primarily opinion-based.

Comment: If the question would use some real-life examples to narrow the discussion it might end up as better suited for codereview.se

Comment: @bjb568 Even best practice is pretty controversial. I've seen people defend the [multiline-braceless-if](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/) to death

Comment: @piotrek, It is a valid question, but somewhat broad and "beginnerish". Unfortunately you will find folks in this forum that would rather chastise you than simply ignore a question they think is is too basic to be answered.

Comment: Also why are people down voting this; when unsure about something asking on meta us exactly the right thing to do

Comment: @JamesHall: Writing a brief, but informative answer to a well-thought-out, specific question is one thing.  Writing a book to try and cover every possible eventuality in a question that demands multiple answers for completeness is quite another.

Comment: That's a good question @RichardTingle.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, yeah. And whether or not to want to have SQL injection is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, good point, context means everything. I mentioned that I thought the question was too broad, but according to piotrek the post was closed for being primarily opinion-based. Depending on the context there are definite answers. Any answers would have inherently helped form a better question, but now we will never know.

Comment: @James Hall the question is not closed. someone who edited my question on meta said it's closed. currently it's put on hold

Comment: @piotrek, Understand, but because it is on "hold" no further answers can be added. correct?

Answer (score 9):

Questions that ask for a "list of things" are frequently closed by the community, because they cannot be definitively answered.

Comment: ...but this can be definitively answered.

Comment: @JamesHall: As a trusted member of the community, can you know that ahead of time, *without having prior knowledge of the problem domain?*

Comment: @James I can think of a few;  nulling out things that don't go out of scope for ages but are large, nulling out no longer accurate information then lazy loading in next access. As a return to signal an error (bad practice), as a return to indicate nothing found. But that's just what I can think of. I bet that list isn't exhaustive